# Update a list of div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json

I have a list of divs, like :

```
<div class="categories" onmouseover="this.style.background='#CCCCCC'" onmouseout="this.style.background='#FFFFFF'">
    <div class="categories1">
        Andy
    </div>

    <div class="categories2">
        Link to Andy
    </div>
</div>

<div class="categories" onmouseover="this.style.background='#CCCCCC'" onmouseout="this.style.background='#FFFFFF'">
    <div class="categories1">
        Mark
    </div>

    <div class="categories2">
        Link to Mark
    </div>
</div>

...

<div class="categories" onmouseover="this.style.background='#CCCCCC'" onmouseout="this.style.background='#FFFFFF'">
    <div class="categories1">
        Yuri
    </div>

    <div class="categories2">
        Link to Yuri
    </div>
</div>
```

Ordered by the name inside `categories1`.

Through AJAX/jQuery I add to the server a new category, and after this operation I'd like to update the list on client-side.

So, I thought to these ways :

1. Select all categories from database after the insert one, create the whole html and refresh the older one with the new one; the faster solution as coding, but if the list is so long, the overhead is big;
2. Load from the server only the created element, browse the DOM trought jQuery, check where to put the element (checking the alphabetic order) and add it;

None of them sound nice to me, so I'll ask to you some suggestions/tips/ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an AJAX call to grab the new elements.  Append it to your containing div.  Then sort all the div's by name using ->

```
//get a raw array of dom nodes
var items = $('.categories1').get();

//empty out the container
$('#container').empty();

//use Array's prototype sort() method
items.sort(function(x,y) {
  return $(x).text() > $(y).text();
});

//iterate through their sorted order, appending their parent back to the container
$(items).each(function() {
    $('#container').append($(this).parent());
});
```

Here's a fiddle to see it in action - http://jsfiddle.net/rz3Ww/

Comment: +1 Very elegant solution. If the list was huge, you could move the `.empty()` statement to before the `sort()`, just to prevent a flash of unordered content whilst processing. Obviously `append()` needs to stay at the end! :)

Comment: @Chris Good suggestion - that would also be a good spot to put up a loading splash screen, if so desired.

Comment: Tried your example, but in fact it doesnt do the right sort: check it out this http://jsfiddle.net/rz3Ww/1/ : Gabba should be before GTW, not after...

Comment: Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/rz3Ww/2/ I added .toLowerCase() in the sorting function.

Comment: Yeah, this works, but only when the page is loaded. If I try to do the sort after the new div appended nothing happens : I append with $("#container").append(data[2]); , then I call your sort function, but it sort nothing

Comment: @markzzz Put the code into a function.  Then call the function in your AJAX callback.

Comment: @John Strickler : yeah is what I've done. Its strange enough : If I open the code (on chrome) and I watch the div, is right ordered. If I open the Inspector the code is not sorted :O

Comment: Yea I noticed something similar which is why I used the .each() to append it back in the sorted order.  It's very strange that it wouldn't work to newly appended DOM nodes...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139428/problem-with-appendsorting-some-divs maybe you'll find interessant :)

Comment: Indeed, I'm following it to see what others are suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to go with your second suggestion - jQuery can very quickly grab all the elements with a class of `category1` and it's trival to parse the text into an array from there. Then all you need to do is find out which element comes just before your new element, find it in the DOM, and add yours after it.

Answer (score 1):

Two things come to mind after reading your question:

1. You are talking about a list, but you're using DIVs.  This isn't the end of the world, but using an unordered list (`<ul>`) would be more semantically appropriate.
2. Since you bring up jQuery, this problem begs for the use of [jQuery Templates plugin](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/).  You are trying to do client-side data binding, and that's exactly what jQuery Templates will help you do.